# Sonarqube and lint with intellij

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint-intellij

I am new to IntelliJ. I want to use sonar Qube and sonar lint in combination with IntelliJ IDE. How to configure sonar Qube and sonar lint plugin in IntelliJ?

I went through some sites which are suggesting me File -> Settings -> Other Settings -> Sonar but in my IntelliJ, there is nothing like Other Settings after opening Settings. I am using IntelliJ Ultimate version 2018.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to install the plugin via File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Search in Repositories.

After the plugin was installed successfully, you will find the described "Other Settings" section: [image]